# datetime2 no longer valid primary key

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

do you know about azure changes, leading to restrict usage of datetime2 for primary keys.
Have a azure database which started throwing warnings for no reason. The warnings itselve made no reason and there was no trace id.

After trying to build the database again, there popped up some new errors, that datetime2 is no longer valid for primary keys.

this is some huge change without notification for the customers. Even the error/warnungs made no sense.

is there a feed, I can subscribe to, to get such information in time and not after they are done?
Or do I see ghosts?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the issue. I was able to create a table using a datetime2 as primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE Events
(
TimeOcurred  DateTime2 PRIMARY KEY,
UserAction   NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
UserId       int
)
```

The compatibility level of the database I used for testing is 140.

Comment: i will investigate further